# Как разделить слова написанные через запятую?

Tags: массивы, php

Как разделить ключевые слова и занести их в массив на `php` которые написаны через запятую?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$pizza  = "piece1, piece2, piece3, piece4, piece5, piece6";
$pieces = explode(",", $pizza);
```

Добавив в код третьей строкой (только лишь для проверки содержимого массива)

```
print_r($pieces);
```

Получим следующий вывод

```
Array ( [0] => piece1 [1] => piece2 [2] => piece3 [3] => piece4 [4] => piece5 [5] => piece6 )
```

Что и требовалось.